# Solution to ODE: integral form of Airy equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, airy-functions

I've been told that the following equation

$$\left(x-\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} \right) y =1$$

has a solution of the form

$$y(x)=\int_0^\infty e^{-t^3/3 - ixt}dt$$

(an exponential of something, but I can't find what's in the exponent)

What's the solution to this equation in terms of the integral of an exponential? $y(x)$ has to vanish as $x\rightarrow \infty$, so I guess the term corresponding to the Bi function is not present.

x is complex

Comment: It is quite famous, maybe you can find something on mathworld or wikipedia

Comment: I've been checking on DLMF because I guess it's related to the Airy function but that 1 on the RHS is killing me

Comment: Have you tried solving it numerically and fit it to some series?

Answer (score 2):

The *Airy integrals* that defines the Airy functions , $\text{Ai}$ and $\text{Bi}$ are

$$
\text{Ai}(x)=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^{\infty}\cos\left(xt+\frac{t^3}{3} \right)~dt\\
\text{Bi}(x)=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^{\infty}\sin\left(xt+\frac{t^3}{3} \right)~dt+\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^{\infty}\exp\left(xt+\frac{t^3}{3} \right)~dt
$$

and *Airy's differential equation* and solution are

$$
\frac{d^2f}{dx^2}-xf=0\\
f=a\text{Ai}(x)+b\text{Bi}(x)
$$

The Airy functions are periodic for negative $x$ and hyperbolic for positive $x$, with $\text{Ai}\to 0 ~\& ~\text{Bi}\to\infty \text{ as } x\to\infty.$

Answer (score 1):

The ODE has a particular solution given by
$$
y(x)=-\int_0^{\infty}\exp\left(-\frac{t^3}{3}+xt\right)dt. \tag{1}
$$
Proof:
\begin{align}
\left(x-\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\right)y(x)&=-\int_0^{\infty}(x-t^2)\exp\left(-\frac{t^3}{3}+xt\right)dt \\
&=-\int_0^{\infty}\exp\left(-\frac{t^3}{3}+xt\right)d\left(-\frac{t^3}{3}+xt\right) \\
&=\int_{-\infty}^0e^udu=1. \qquad{\square} \tag{2}
\end{align}
Remark: $y(x)=-\pi\text{Hi}(x)$, where $\text{Hi}(x)$ is one of [Scorer's functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scorer%27s_function).